# Import Eclipse Project from Github to Android Studio - Parse.com tutorial

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I want to import a project from this site https://github.com/ParsePlatform/AnyWall to android studio. When I do it there is a bunch of errors. If I did something wrong? This is what i'm doing step by step.

1. Download ZIP
2. Open android studio
3. Import project
4. Select AnyWall-android
5. Create project from existing sources
6. No change in Project name and Project location
7. Mark all
8. All libraries selected
9. All modules selected
10. Choose API19
11. All AndroidManifest selected
12. Import Android Dependencies From Property Files (Add dependency Anywall selected)
13. Adding my Parse application id and client key in Application.java.
14. Adding my Google Maps Android API v2 key in AndroidManifest.xml
15. Run
16. Choosing my phone
17. Errors

    ```
    Error:(33, 39) java: cannot find symbol
    symbol:   class LocationServices
    location: package com.google.android.gms.location
    Error:(35, 41) java: package com.google.android.gms.common.api does not exist
    Error:(57, 20) java: package GoogleApiClient does not exist
    Error:(58, 20) java: package GoogleApiClient does not exist
    Error:(132, 11) java: cannot find symbol
    symbol:   class GoogleApiClient
    location: class com.parse.anywall.MainActivity
    Error:(158, 23) java: cannot find symbol
    symbol:   variable LocationServices
    location: class com.parse.anywall.MainActivity
    Error:(157, 41) java: package GoogleApiClient does not exist
    Error:(411, 3) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    Error:(469, 21) java: package LocationServices does not exist
    Error:(487, 30) java: package LocationServices does not exist
    ```

Comment: This depends on Google Location Services. Make sure you are importing play-services (specifically location if you don't want it all) https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup. This is what it can't find. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationServices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to your app build.gradle google play services dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

This is my app build.gradle after importing project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
     compileSdkVersion 23
      buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

     defaultConfig {
          applicationId "com.parse.anywall"
          minSdkVersion 11
          targetSdkVersion 23
     }

     buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
         }
     }  
 }    
 dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.6.0.jar')
 }
```

Comment: did you solve the issue importing eclipse project? the right way is  importing from existing sources. your project structure should be like this picture http://i.stack.imgur.com/TNb2p.png

Comment: I cant find build.gradle file. I import this project again with gradle option but there is no gradle file or any other file. Just some libs.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/qUdWVO6.png  1. Import project (eclipse etc)
2. AnyWall-android file
3. Import project from external model (Gradle)
4. Use local gradle distribution (default gradle wrapper disabled) gradle home: D:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-2.8

Comment: I download zip from github and extracted to test your enviroment :). When importing eclipse project to Android Studio, don't import from the top folder ../AnyWall-android because Android will detect as Eclipse Project. Import from ../AnyWall-android/AnyWall and Android Studio will create your project as Gradle project

Comment: Just go to File->New->Import Project

Comment: ok, but now i have 99 errors but the gradle aint one :) http://pastebin.com/y9spAexG

Comment: Ok thats another issues :). If you find my help valuable, i'will apreciate if you mark as ansewered ;)

Comment: and you have no errors? :( why this happens to me :(

Comment: i post my build.gradle. I hope it help!!

Comment: my phone have android 4.4 (api19) this 99 errors is from that api. If I set compilesdkversion=23 then it will run on my phone?

Comment: yes, minSdkVersion value is 11, so in your device should work.

Comment: Thank you very much :) :) You help me a lot :)

Comment: I'm glad to help you :)